# How does the Segwit2x fork implement replay protection?

Tags: blockchain-fork, segwit2x, replay-attack

The creators of the Segwit2x fork claim that they are working on some sort of replay protection. What replay protection do they have and how does this replay protection work?

Answer (score 3):

segwit2x temporarily had an opt-in replay protection, but chose to remove it.

it is intentional, as part of their strategy to make only one fork survive.

Comment: Interesting, do you have any thoughts on this: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/61524/if-btc2x-doesnt-have-replay-protection-does-that-mean-all-btc-transactions-can

Comment: So does it mean they will ***NOT*** implement a reply protection at all?